# push! overwrites earlier elements in Julia

Tags: arrays, julia

In Julia (0.6.2), push! occasionally overwrites all previous elements with the last element pushed. Here is a piece of code where it appeared; in the end, `out` consists of identical entries.

```
using Distributions
l = [(0, 10, 1, [1.1; 2.2], [1/3; 2/3], 4)];
out = Array{Float64}[ ]; # output
entry = zeros(Float64,3);
for i = 1:length(l)
    row = l[i];
    startingtime = row[1];
    finishingtime = row[2];
    node = row[3];
    sizelist = row[4];
    sizedistr = row[5];
    density = row[6];
    t = startingtime;
    deltat = rand(Exponential(1/density));
    while t + deltat < finishingtime
        t = t + deltat;
        filetype = rand(Categorical(sizedistr));
        size = sizelist[filetype];
        entry[1] = t; entry[2] = node; entry[3] = size;
        print(entry,"\n");
        push!(out, entry);
        deltat = rand(Exponential(density));
    end;
end;

out
```

I am a bit worried about reproducibility, because in other similar situations, push! worked fine. So... is this an actual bug? Or is there a simple fix to this? Thanks in advance!

Edit: OK, to clarify: by reproducability, I mean that in many other situations, push! works fine, and I don't see a particular pattern for it. It might even happen that on another computer, this code runs fine. I don't know. But for some reason, for me, the above code does not work properly: for each run, it produces an `out` consisting of identical entries. Here is one output:

```
[0.175033, 1.0, 2.2]
[0.24153, 1.0, 2.2]
[4.95478, 1.0, 2.2]
[7.46299, 1.0, 2.2]
Array{Float64,N} where N[[7.46299, 1.0, 2.2], [7.46299, 1.0, 2.2], [7.46299, 1.0, 2.2], [7.46299, 1.0, 2.2]]
```

The print output also shows that the entries are actually different when generated, but they get rewritten after `push!`. This phenomenon also happened for some other code not containing randomness, but it's too long (and I don't even know which parts are relevant to the bug, so I can't even reduce it) so I try to avoid including it here.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `push!`. You have a while loop dependent on a random variable. That's why you get different results between runs. Maybe look into `srand()` if you want reproducible code with random numbers.

Comment: This does not answer my question. Even if the elements are random, `out` should consist of different entries (e.g. because the value of `t` is increased in each loop). Also, it happened with other code not including any randomness as well, but it's overly long.

Comment: Running with `srand(1)` before the for-loop I'm consistently getting the following: `[0.138143, 1.0, 2.2]
[1.85669, 1.0, 1.1]
[3.48218, 1.0, 1.1]` No duplications here. Maybe try fixing the randomness and show that you indeed have this issue. There is no way `push!` would randomly overwrite elements.

Comment: As I said, the same phenomenon occurred with code with no randomness at all. What's worse, in that piece, I was creating 3 separate collections, and for 2 out of 3, it worked properly, for 1, it produced the above phenomenon.

Comment: I added `srand(1)` at the beginning, now I consistently get this (sorry for the poor formatting): `[0.138143, 1.0, 2.2]
[1.85669, 1.0, 1.1]
[3.48218, 1.0, 1.1]
Array{Float64,N} where N[[3.48218, 1.0, 1.1], [3.48218, 1.0, 1.1], [3.48218, 1.0, 1.1]]`

Comment: And what's wrong with this? The first element of the array is changing as `t` is increasing and the other 2 stay the same. This is the expected behaviour right?

Comment: No. In the output I provided, the first 3 arrays are the output of `print()` inside the loop (which look good), and the last `Array...` part is the value of `out`, containing repeated entries, which is not good.

Comment: The "push" tag is for git push. I changed that to "arrays".

Comment: Now I get your point. Indeed you're mutating the entry array as the answers have pointed out.

Answer (score 2):

You are appending the *same* `entry` vector to `out` in each iteration of the loop. And at every iteration, you're just mutating `entry`, effectively mutating it for all instances in your final `out` array.

This is much easier to see with a simpler block of code:

```
julia> entry = zeros(3);
julia> out = [];
julia> for i in 1:3
         entry[1] = rand()
         @show entry
         push!(out, entry)
       end
entry = [0.580382, 0.0, 0.0]
entry = [0.210324, 0.0, 0.0]
entry = [0.658214, 0.0, 0.0]
julia> out
3-element Array{Any,1}:
 [0.658214, 0.0, 0.0]
 [0.658214, 0.0, 0.0]
 [0.658214, 0.0, 0.0]
```

The final `out` contains what appears to be repeated elements because every element in it is the *same* vector which you have been modifying in the loop:

```
julia> out[1] === out[2] === out[3]
true
```

If you want each entry in `out` to be a separate vector, then you need to either construct a new `entry` at each iteration or `copy()` it before pushing it into `out`. For example:

```
julia> out = [];
julia> for i in 1:3
         entry[1] = rand()
         @show entry
         push!(out, copy(entry))
       end
entry = [0.992697, 0.0, 0.0]
entry = [0.0971598, 0.0, 0.0]
entry = [0.918921, 0.0, 0.0]
julia> out
3-element Array{Any,1}:
 [0.992697, 0.0, 0.0] 
 [0.0971598, 0.0, 0.0]
 [0.918921, 0.0, 0.0]
```

If you don't want to `copy()` then instead of:

```
entry[1] = t; entry[2] = node; entry[3] = size;
print(entry,"\n");
push!(out, entry);
```

Just do:

```
push!(out,[t,node,size]);
```

Answer (score 1):

That has nothing to do with randomness or `push!`. You just always push the same array, which is essentially a pointer, to `out`, while changing its contents every time:

```
julia> entry = zeros(Float64, 3)
3-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.0
 0.0
 0.0

julia> out = Array{Float64}[]
0-element Array{Array{Float64,N} where N,1}

julia> for t = 1:3
           entry[1], entry[2], entry[3] = rand(), rand(), rand()
           println(entry)
           push!(out, entry)
           println(out)
       end
[0.913257, 0.413237, 0.612766]
Array{Float64,N} where N[[0.913257, 0.413237, 0.612766]]
[0.00247971, 0.0204771, 0.891242]
Array{Float64,N} where N[[0.00247971, 0.0204771, 0.891242], [0.00247971, 0.0204771, 0.891242]]
[0.847745, 0.742295, 0.0260808]
Array{Float64,N} where N[[0.847745, 0.742295, 0.0260808], [0.847745, 0.742295, 0.0260808], [0.847745, 0.742295, 0.0260808]]

julia> pointer(out[1])
Ptr{Float64} @0x00007f7e0abfaf20

julia> pointer(out[2])
Ptr{Float64} @0x00007f7e0abfaf20
```

See that? Essentially, every time, you change the same `entry`, and just end up having the same reference three times in `out`.

How to avoid that? Just assign `entry` inside the loop:

```
julia> out = Array{Float64}[]
0-element Array{Array{Float64,N} where N,1}

julia> for t = 1:3
           entry = rand(3)
           println(entry)
           push!(out, entry)
           println(out)
       end
[0.141818, 0.743078, 0.760137]
Array{Float64,N} where N[[0.141818, 0.743078, 0.760137]]
[0.625746, 0.558617, 0.633356]
Array{Float64,N} where N[[0.141818, 0.743078, 0.760137], [0.625746, 0.558617, 0.633356]]
[0.337548, 0.55715, 0.78439]
Array{Float64,N} where N[[0.141818, 0.743078, 0.760137], [0.625746, 0.558617, 0.633356], [0.337548, 0.55715, 0.78439]]
```

Then you can remove the outer declaration completely. You can't avoid having 3 separate `entry`s, because you actually need that much allocation, if you want them to be different...

---

Oh, and no need for those semicolons. Julia doesn't automatically print anything, like Matlab, if that was your motivation.